# Using ConfigurationBuilder with standalone libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, configurationmanager

I'm converting a library from .NET framework to .NET standard and as a part of this need to move over to the new ConfigurationBuilder style for config management.

The library is referenced by multiple components including web applications and class libraries using either .NET framework or .NET core.

The library has it's own config file and internal class for configuration management.

The following is a cut down example:

```
internal interface IConfigManager
{
    string Name { get; }
}

internal class ConfigManager : IConfigManager
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public ConfigManager()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("configTestLibSettings.json");

        this._config = builder.Build();
    }

    public string Name => this._config["name"];
}

public interface IConfigTestLib
{
    string GetName();
}

public class ConfigTestLib : IConfigTestLib
{
    private readonly IConfigManager _configManager = new ConfigManager();

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this._configManager.Name;
    }
}
```

For most consumers of the library this works fine, all I need to do is make sure configTestLibSettings.json is copied to the output folder and the class works as expected.

However for a .NET Framework Web Application `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` actually returns the location for IISExpress, not the build location. Therefore the config file is not found.

Is it possible to get around this?

I'm aware that I could get the value of `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` in my web application and pass this in as a base path via dependency injection, however I don't really want to drastically change the interface to my library.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
    internal class ConfigManager : IConfigManager
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public ConfigManager()
        {
            var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            var uri = new Uri(codeBase);

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.LocalPath))
                .AddJsonFile("configTestLibSettings.json");

            this._config = builder.Build();
        }

        public string Name => this._config["name"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *Directory.GetCurrentDirectory*, can't you just use

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: I had considered that option however the location property points to the actual file rather than the folder. I just tried var uri = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); which works for a .NET core console app but not for a .NET framework web application